# How are CPU register addresses in crash reports useful in analysis?

Tags: c++, macos, crash, processor

Apple generates these crash logs and my thread 0 has crashed but this question is not about that. This is generic question and I'm wondering how can we make use of these processor register values in crash analysis? How do they help you investigating your crash? Only thing that comes to my mind is if any of the register has NULL pointer like `rcx` in following which gives you an idea about possible null pointer dereference in the code, is that correct assumption?

```
Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000001046e17a0  rbx: 0x00000001043665f0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x00000001046e14f0
  rdi: 0x00000001046e14e0  rsi: 0x00000001046314e8  rbp: 0x00007fff5b89f890  rsp: 0x00007fff5b89f7e0
   r8: 0x00007fff686a7690   r9: 0x0000000000000250  r10: 0x00007fffa2478201  r11: 0x000000000009ea18
  r12: 0x00000001046b11d8  r13: 0x00007fff686a75c8  r14: 0x00007fff686ae638  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00000001043601be  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000060

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: They help in all kinds of ways; the mere fact you can see what lies at a memory address or what the value is of a register helps tremendously...

Comment: @l'L'l thats true but what are some ways you use it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the register RIP (Instruction Pointer) to determine which machine instruction it failed on. I'm not sure if GDB works on Mac OSx but in Linux you can use GDB (GNU Debugger) then to analyze the assembly instructions to find the exact instruction that produced the error. Additionally, the registers RBP (Frame Pointer) and RSP (Stack Pointer) point to the bottom and top of the stack in memory respectively. Knowing all these, you can view exactly what the stack was at the time of the crash and which instruction caused the crash.

Comment: OS X used to use gdb, however, nowadays lldb is standard.

Comment: `-fomit-frame-pointer` has the default (even for 32-bit code) for a few years now, so RBP is just another register (like RBX or R12-R15), not the frame pointer.  That kind of stack-unwinding requires metadata (from the `.eh_frame` section) and the contents of stack memory, so you can get it if you have a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @nrabbit said, you can also use the registers to understand what the values of some of the arguments to the function were and what the result of the function call was if you know the calling conventions of the code. [Here are some examples of Intel calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). So the `eax` register normally holds a function result in 32-bit programs, for example.

Comment: Only if you know the crash happened on a function CALL or RET instruction.  Inside a function, the registers are all temporary scratch space until the final modification of `eax` produces the return value.  Functions modify their arg registers, too.  So you just have to look at the asm at the crash location to figure out what that means for the C variables involved.  **There's nothing useful you can say without looking carefully at the asm for the code around the value of RIP.**